# Paypal Payflow pro error "Invalid path was requested"

Tags: paypal

Trying to implement transparent redirect with paypal and getting the error "Invalid path was requested". Does anyone know what this is? Doesn't seems to be included in the documentation.

Comment: What endpoint are you sending the request to?

Comment: I had the same issue with https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com, https://payflowlink.paypal.com seems to be working still though. Just make sure your MODE=TEST.